# Sum of independent non-identically distributed Bernoulli distributions

Tags: probability, probability-theory, random-variables

Let $X_i$ be independent Bernoulli distributions of parameter $p_i$, $X_i \sim \text{Ber}(p_i)$. I was wondering whether there is any expression for the distribution of the sum of $n$ such variables

$$Y = \sum_{i=1}^n X_i$$

I know that it is possible to derive a result for the distribution of the sum if all $X_i$ are identically distributed, i.e. $p_i = p$. Are there any conditions on the distribution of $p_i$ for which it is possible to derive an analytical expression for the distribution of $Y$?

Comment: You are not going to be able to do much better than the probability generating function, so $P(Y=m)$ is the coefficient of $z^m$ in the expansion of $\prod\limits_{i=1}^n (1-p_i+p_iz)$